# Simple way to stub an element with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm just starting to learn to use JAXB to marshal my java objects into XML.  I've got no problem serializing objects, but now what I want to do is insert an element into the xml for which there is no corresponding POJO.

For example, I have a list of `Folder`s, and I want to put each `Folder` into an xml element called `Folders`.  Does this make sense?  I could just write `<Folders>` and `</Folders>` to the output stream where appropriate, but I'd like to do this in a more formal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JAXB with StAX to do this.  Using a `XMLStreamWriter` will help formalize the interaction with the XML and give you better control over such this as encodings:

```
package forum8406266;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Folder.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

        List<Folder> folders = new ArrayList<Folder>(3);
        folders.add(new Folder());
        folders.add(new Folder());
        folders.add(new Folder());

        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
        xsw.writeStartDocument();
        xsw.writeStartElement("Folders");

        for(Folder folder : folders) {
            marshaller.marshal(folder, xsw);
        }

        xsw.writeEndElement();
        xsw.writeEndDocument();
        xsw.flush();
    }

}
```

The above code assumes that your `Folder` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`:

```
package forum8406266;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Folder")
public class Folder {

}
```

Comment: This works well, thank you.  I get an extraneous `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` with each call of `marshal`, but this is probably a different issue.

Comment: You need to make sure you set the JAXB_FRAGMENT property on the Marshaller.